# AFNetworking response

Tags: web-services, ios5, afnetworking

```
MyHttpClient *sharedHttpClient = [MyHttpClient sharedClient];
[sharedHttpClient getPath:BASERURL_GENERAL_APPEND_PATH parameters:reqParameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *mOperation , id responseObject){
   NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);


}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error){

   //code for failure


}];
```

i got request as success but it returns response data as NSData type ,i need response string.please help ...

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `NSString`'s initWithData:encoding found in the docs https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Otherwise you may want to check your web services return `content-type`

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside the success block:

```
NSString* response = [mOperation responseString];
```

If this string is nil, there might be an encoding problem. Check the content-type of your web service.